# On a dataset made up of dictionaries, how do I multiply the elements of each dictionary with Python'

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, dataset

I started coding in Python 4 days ago, so I'm a complete newbie. I have a dataset that comprises an undefined number of dictionaries. Each dictionary is the x and y of a point in the coordinates.

I'm trying to compute the summatory of x*y by nesting the loop that multiplies x*y within the loop that sums the products.

However I haven't been able to figure out how to multiply the values for the two keys in each dictionary (so far I only got to multiply all the x*y)

So far I've got this:

If my data set were to be d= [{'x':0, 'y':0}, {'x':1, 'y':1}, {'x':2, 'y':3}]

I've got the code for the function that calculates the product of each pair of x and y:

```
def product_xy (product_x_per_y):
    prod_xy =[]
    n = 0
    for i in range (len(d)):
       result = d[n]['x']*d[n]['y']
       prod_xy.append(result)
       n+1
    return prod_xy
```

I also have the function to add up the elements of a list (like prod_xy):

```
def total_xy_prod (sum_prod):
    all = 0
    for s in sum_prod:
        all+= s
    return all
```

I've been trying to find a way to nest this two functions so that I can iterate through the multiplication of each x*y and then add up all the products.

Comment: Please update your question to provide an example of your relevant code so far.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure your code works as expected

First, your functions have a few mistakes. For example, in `product_xy`, you assign `n=0`, and later do `n + 1`; you probably meant to do `n += 1` instead of `n + 1`. But `n` is also completely unnecessary; you can simply use the `i` from the `range` iteration to replace `n` like so: `result = d[i]['x']*d[i]['y']`

## Nesting these two functions: part 1

To answer your question, it's fairly straightforward to get the sum of the products of the elements from your current code:

```
coord_sum = total_xy_prod(product_xy(d))
```

## Nesting these two functions: part 2

However, there is a much shorter and more efficient way to tackle this problem. For one, Python provides the built-in function [sum()](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) to sum the elements of a list (and other iterables), so there's no need create `total_xy_prod`. Our code could at this point read as follows:

```
coord_sum = sum(product_xy(d))
```

But `product_xy` is also unnecessarily long and inefficient, and we could also replace it entirely with a shorter expression. In this case, the shortening comes from generator expressions, which are basically compact for-loops. The Python docs give some of the basic details of how the syntax works at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which are distinct, but closely related to generator expressions. For the purposes of answering this question, I will simply present the final, most simplified form of your desired result:

```
coord_sum = sum(e['x'] * e['y'] for e in d)
```

Here, the generator expression iterates through every element in `d` (using `for e in d`), multiplies the numbers stored in the dictionary keys 'x' and 'y' of each element (using `e['x'] * e['y']`), and then sums each of those products from the entire sequence.

There is also some documentation on [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), but it's a bit technical, so it's probably not approachable for the Python beginner.